# Invoking an argo workflow container with optional flags?

Tags: argo-workflows

Say I have a dockerized command that can take an optional flag, similar to how `ls` can take a flag `-l`.

How can I make argo invoke it properly, allowing the caller to choose whether to include the flag or not?

This does not work, but hopefully it is somewhat close and demonstrates my intent:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: do-work-
spec:
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: long-format
        value: false

  entrypoint: do-work

  templates:
    - name: do-work
      container:
        image: alpine:3.7
        command: [ls]
        args:
          - "{{workflow.parameters.long-format == 'true' ? '-l' : '' }}"
          - /etc
```

If I invoke it like `argo submit do-work.yaml` or `argo submit do-work.yaml -p long-format=false` then I want it to run `ls /etc`.

If I invoke it like `argo submit do-work.yaml -p long-format=true` then I want it to run `ls -l /etc`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that something like this can work, using python to jam them all together into one string... kind of ugly.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: do-work-
spec:
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: dir
        value: /etc
      - name: long-format
        value: false

  entrypoint: main

  templates:
    - name: main
      dag:
        tasks:
          - name: build-cli-args
            template: build-cli-args
          - name: do-work
            depends: build-cli-args
            template: do-work
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: cli-args
                  value: '{{tasks.build-cli-args.outputs.result}}'

    - name: build-cli-args
      script:
        image: python:alpine3.6
        command: [python]
        source: |
          cli_args = [
            "-l" if "{{workflow.parameters.long-format}}" == "true" else None,
            "{{workflow.parameters.dir}}",
          ]
          print(" ".join([a for a in cli_args if a is not None]))

    - name: do-work
      inputs: 
        parameters:
          - name: cli-args
      script:
        image: alpine:3.7
        command: [sh, -ex]
        source: |
          ls {{inputs.parameters.cli-args}}
```

I will leave the question open in case someone can tell me how to do it more minimally, with an expression like I was attempting.

Answer (score 0):

After encountering a similar issue I might have a potential solution.

The main problem here is that the `args` field is a fixed-length array, where the absence of the flag forces an empty string that messes up with the command.

In order to avoid this issue it's possible to use the `podSpecPatch` field
(it barely appears in the documentation, but an example is provided [here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/pod-spec-patch.yaml))

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: do-work-
spec:
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: long-format
        value: false

  entrypoint: do-work

  templates:
    - name: do-work
      container:
        image: alpine:3.7
        command: [ls]
        podSpecPatch: '{"containers":[{"name":"main", "args": {{=toJson(filter([workflow.parameters.long-format == "true" ? "-l" : '', "/etc"], { len(#) > 0 }))}}}]}'
```

`podSpecPatch` enables to override the pod's `spec` fields with a string this is interesting because it's basically impossible to dynamically manipulate the arrays of `args`, but it's possible to play with the `podSpecPatch` variable.

In the (untested sorry) template above, the `spec` for the "main" `container` is modified for the `args` field.
The initial array is filtered: no empty strings in the resulting array fed to the pod.